# Failed to set up HTTPS on WAMPSERVER 2.5

Tags: php, apache, https, wamp, wampserver

I am using **WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.5) 2.5**, and I need to set up **HTTPS** for my websites, so I have followed the instruction from the links below,

http://developersdigest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/wamp-server-2-https-ssl-configuration.html

and have also tried this one,

http://indiesphp.com/setup-httpsssl-on-wamp-server/

In the DOS Command windows, I enter httpd -t . it displays `Syntax is OK`.

But it says `Unable to connect` on my firefox when I hit `https://{{localhost}}/`

Any idea what I missed?

Comment: You restarted apache before testing, right?

Comment: yes I did. and I even have tried to restart my entire machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if www project link are not include localhost?

Just to Edit wamp/www/index.php line 30

> **$suppress_localhost = true;**

just change to

> **$suppress_localhost = false;**

Comment: I couldn't find this line in my index.php. what do I do?

Comment: this problem occur only wamp server 2.5 version.it this your wamp server version? @Faizan